# Why was my suggested edit rejected as "incorrect" when it contains no factual information?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, specific-edit

I recently made an edit to a question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2922502

One member approved the edit and then three more rejected it as "incorrect" which makes absolutely no sense because the additions are highlighting, further documentation on classes, and my attempt to dumb down the explanation of what exactly a class is (the same explanation I was given when I first learn object oriented programming and the same explanation that's found [here](http://suite101.com/a/programming-in-simple-steps-the-class-a74162)).

How is any of this incorrect? It could be that they disagree with the explanation, but it's not something to be taken literally, it's just a very basic explanation because OP had no comprehension of what a class is and what its function is.

Can someone please explain to me why this was rejected?

Comment: The etiquette here says we should not modify an answer so much, specially a recent answer, unless it's marked as community wiki.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that. Why mark it as incorrect? That's just horribly confusing.

Comment: @ZachSmith Read past the fourth word.  "This edit is incorrect **or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.**"  Your edit is an attempt to reply to the existing post.

Comment: "Radical change" could also have been used as a reason. I guess the reviewers thought you should have posted your additions as a comment (which is mentioned in the "incorrect" reason text).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the rejection reason isn't *wrong* per say (your edit is really an "an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post"), it probably would have been more helpful for you if they had instead used the following rejection reason:

> **radical change**
>
> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.

The idea of suggested edits is that you should not be changing, adding, or removing, the true *content* of the post.  You should simply be making the author's existing content more "accessible" to the reader.  Edits can fix grammar, spelling, make wording changes to help make the post clearer without changing its meaning at all, etc.

As soon as your edit is changing what the post means, it's content, etc. then it's not appropriate; it's not what the suggested edit system is there for.

If you would like to add something to an answer you can comment on it, or if you have enough more to add you can add a new answer to the question, optionally referencing portions of an existing answer as a starting place.  If the original author would like to incorporate your additions into his own answer (with proper attribution) they are welcome to.  However (and this is important) they are not *required* to.  If the author doesn't agree with your changes, feels they are incorrect, misleading, overly complicated, or whatever, they aren't obligated to include them since it's *their answer*.

All of this of course goes out the window for posts marked as Community Wiki.  The whole point of such a designation is that none of this applies, and that edits are allowed to change the *content* of the post; it is not the views of one particular author.