# My edit on SO was rejected, which I believe added value

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I edited a question believing it to add value to an answer, clarifying something I believe important.

[The Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2924364)

The edit rejection reason was:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

It is neither incorrect nor an attempt at anything other than an improvement.

From this rejection, I'm a bit unsure as to what is deemed as an acceptable edit and improvement.  I'm not moaning, at all, just getting a grasp on what's good, what's not and if this was a correct decision (no need to be gentle with your comments...).

The answer suggested PHP short code tag `<?=` is available, which became available as of PHP 5.4.0. However the statement was too general - "you can use things like short tags" - and did not make it clear that there two types of short tags, the other of which might well not work, and is why I specifically stated in my edit suggestion the use of `<?` is not advised.

I see many questions with people still using these short tags, and so my edit would promote a more concise answer and attempt to avoid any confusion or promote bad coding practices.

As the question was viewed 13,6728 times, and the answer was highly voted, I thought this point would be worth clarifying, to improve the site and the info it provides.

All that said, I can see how decisions on post edits could be difficult to decide, political etc.

[How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) States:

> If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!
>
> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date.

Comment: Personally, I'd put those types of things in a comment - not sure myself though whether that's going too far in an edit or not.

Comment: hmm.. I did think about a comment, but not everyone reads them, and possibly less likely to read an answer which is accepted and with 89 upvotes. With those kind of stats one expects to be reading top notch info.

Comment: Since the edit seems reasonable, [I edited it in.](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1100424/6)

Comment: I think it is a reasonable one. However, only if the reviewer has some knowledge about php that they can make such judgment.

Comment: An alternative where you think an existing answer is wrong/lacking is to provide an alternative answer

Comment: Closely related, if not even duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196917/186381

Comment: Thanks @AsheeshR, was defo worth doing

Comment: @Servy: I don't think it is related/dupe. The basic issue is the same, edit rejected, but the reasons and arguments and even coding language are different/unique.

Comment: @James Not really.  I looked through this to be sure, but the answer I gave to that question is pretty much an *exact* answer to this question in my mind.  I see nothing about this question that differentiates it or makes that answer not apply.  The language of the code is irrelevant to whether or not this style of edit is allowable.  Now I'd say that with your edit, "is an attempt to reply" probably is better than "radical change", but other than that, the rest of the reasoning seems to apply just fine to this post.